# Why do I get ```TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken``` after I include "use client" in my Next.js file.?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentful

I'm getting a "Failed to compile" message in my Next.js website when I'm trying to fetch data from Contentful.

```
- error ./src\components\Carousel\Carousel.js
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

   ,-[C:\Users\Sibusiso\Desktop\Test\client\src\components\Carousel\Carousel.js:1:1]
 1 | // "use client";
 2 | import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   :                           ^^^^^^^^^
 3 | import { client } from '@/client';
 4 |
 4 | const Carousel = () => {
   `----

Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":
  ./src\components\Carousel\Carousel.js
  ./src\app\page.js
```

So I included `"use client"` at the top of my Carousel.js file, but after that I got a Unhandled Runtime Error `TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken`

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { client } from '@/client';

const Carousel = () => {

  const [isCarouselLoading, setIsCarouselLoading] = useState(false);
  const [carouselSlides, setCarouselSlides] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCarouselSlides = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await client.getEntries({ type: "luminCarousel"});
        // const responseData = response.items;
        console.log(res)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getCarouselSlides();
  }, []);
```

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken

Source
src\client.js (5:22) @ contentful

  3 | console.log(process.env);
  4 | 
> 5 | export const client = contentful.createClient({
    |                    ^
  6 | space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  7 | environment: 'master', // defaults to 'master' if not set
  8 | accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The accessToken and space ID are in my .env.development file (I tried a plain .env file and there was no change).
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular the part about not posting pictures of code. Furthermore you also need to provide a real [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i have this problem too. could you fix it?

Comment: i have the same issie :/

Comment: The error already tells you the problem, so: did you mark `page.js` as `"use client"` too, as it's asking?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same issue. If I call API from getStaticProps, Its working fine, but not when I call from useEffect.

solution is to copy env file variable in next.config.js file, that's how contentful createClient method will access env file in client side.

this is what my next.config.js looks like

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID:process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_SECRET: process.env.CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_SECRET,
    CONTENTFUL_REVALIDATE_SECRET: process.env.CONTENTFUL_REVALIDATE_SECRET,
    CONTENTFUL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN: process.env.CONTENTFUL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution within Next.js docs.

[Next Js docs on env variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser)

*In order to make the value of an environment variable accessible in the browser, Next.js can "inline" a value, at build time, into the js bundle that is delivered to the client, replacing all references to process.env.[variable] with a hard-coded value. To tell it to do this, you just have to prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_.*

For example: `NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=abcdefghijk`

Once you do this you just call them with `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID`